# How do you prepare Jello with fruit pieces?

Tags: gelatin

I would like to make individual containers of Jello with fruit pieces, but the fruit always sinks to the bottom,is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only trick I know is to let it start to firm up before mixing in the fruit.  You can pour a layer, let it slightly firm up (it'll be kinda a thick goo), add the fruit and the rest of the mix.

... but you don't want to let it set up completely; then you'll just have two layers that haven't bonded well with fruit stuck in there.

Exact time for it to gel depends on what temperature you're resting it, and the size of the container you're chilling it in (mostly it's a matter of surface to mass ratio)

Comment: I should mention -- the two layers that aren't bonded isn't an issue if you're making individual portions, so everyone gets a little cup.  It's only an issue if you're making a large tray and then cutting it into squares and serving those.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need two boxes of Jello.

1. Make the first box.
2. Fill up your glasses half way and put them in the refrigerator to start solidifying

   - Added bonus: Tilt the glasses in the fridge
3. Put your fruit in
4. Make the second box, use it to fill up the glasses to the top

   - Bonus: Use different colors of Jello!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm good at this, ok all you need is 1 large box of jello , or 2 regular boxes of jello. Now all you do is make the jello like it says on the box, if you use to box's,  you will have to use 2 cups of water, and 1 big box of jello is 2 cups of water as well. Boil the 2 cups of water, then add the jello and boil until the jello is completely dissolved. Now in a bowl or whatever your going to put the jello in, you put the canned fruit in the container,   drain the canned fruit but keep the juice from the canned fruit. Now after the jello is dissolved ( straight from the oven top) pour the jello into the container with the fruit and stir the fruit with the gelatin. Now add 2 cups of cold water, or some kind of juice (I use the juice from the canned fruit that's why I save it), stir it again, and put it in the refrigerator.  The fruit will be throughout the gelatin (the cold liquid is what makes the fruit rise a little so all of the fruit won't sink to the bottom.